# how to always keep files on two servers in sync

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am really new to this so this might sound like a noob question.

I have a user management application running on a server with Windows server 2012. I have another server pc with same OS and same application as a backup.

Users will frequently login to my system and upload files. If my main server crashes I can boot the backup within seconds and restore service, but I will lose all the uploaded files. Is there a solution for this?

I don't want to use drop box cause my data is sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2012 includes a service called *DFS Replication* that enable to have file replication among File Shares.

[DFS Namespaces and DFS Replication Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127250.aspx)